# xpath use when exact attribute name is not known

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath

I am trying to get list values in:

[image]

Though I can extract them with,

```
for r in g.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//ul//li[contains(@data-bib-id, "bib")]'):
    print(r.text)
```

the attribute (**data-bib-id**) is not always the same and I am trying to make my scraping task as generic as possible. So, is there a way that I can extract the same info when the exact attribute is not known? That is, **li** showing up under a **ul** or **ol** or **div** with an attribute value containing a subtext "**bib**" or "**ref**"?

Comment: What about the //ul[@class='rlist separator']//li

Comment: The ways in which people misuse XML never cease to amaze me. What on earth were they thinking of? Did they do this just to torment you?

Answer (score 0):

In case `li` elements can be below `ul` or `ol` or `div` maybe we can omit this detail and start the expression with `//li`?
If so you can add a logic **or** operator on the `data-bib-id` attribute value in your XPath expression so it will be as following:

```py
for r in g.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//li[contains(@data-bib-id, "bib") or contains(@data-bib-id, "bib")]'):
    print(r.text)
```

In case you need to limit the search so that `li` mast be child of `ul` or `ol` or `div` parent element you need to add logic or case on parent nodes so your XPath expression can be as following:

```py
for r in g.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//ul//li[contains(@data-bib-id, "bib") or contains(@data-bib-id, "bib")] or //ol//li[contains(@data-bib-id, "bib") or contains(@data-bib-id, "bib")] //div//li[contains(@data-bib-id, "bib") or contains(@data-bib-id, "bib")]'):
    print(r.text)
```

Comment: Thanks Prophet! But the last expression you gave is the same with what I mentioned in my post, and indeed it works. Sorry for my lack of clear explanation. I am scraping thousands of web sites and the attribute name "data-bib-id" is not always the same it is just an example. What I would like to learn is if it would be possible to apply xpath expression without specifying an attribute name with 'contains'? e.g., //li[STH_GENERIC, "bib"] ...

Comment: Ah, ok. So, please define clearly what do know about that generic locator / element attributes?